# I tried to install openjdk-8-jdk, but it fails

Tags: software-installation

I used following command sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
But got following

```
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jre_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-8-jre_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64 (8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jdk_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jdk:amd64 (8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-8-jre_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody help me ?
Regards
Raivo

Comment: Start by exploring `unable to open '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd.dpkg-new': No such file or directory`. Does that file exist? Is a directory missing?

Comment: what happens if you do `sudo apt update` before executing the command above?